# Cell displays "formula phrase error" is there a way to get the content of the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Some of my data contain "=" at the beginning. I was able to collect and organize them to one sheet using ImportRange and Query, but then when I pasted the query output as value to another worksheet, they are not recognized as valid cell values anymore because of the equal sign.

I tried to get the cell contents using direct reference and concatenate, but all functions returned "formula phrase error".

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lR8Iedr.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scientific notations are not supported in such format you attempt to, hence those errors. here is a quick fix - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and do:

[image: 0]

---

you need to insert something between `=4.6` and `E3` like:

- `&`
- `+`
- `-`
- `/`
- `*`
- `&" "&`
- etc.

Comment: I have thousands of cells with this type of format, can you think of any formulas or tricks that might help?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AIas6oqTBGrfX-M8s8G-dIM8999yvcA5TbDxRGo_CTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: oops sorry: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AIas6oqTBGrfX-M8s8G-dIM8999yvcA5TbDxRGo_CTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Isaac check your sheet (is that what you want?)

Comment: Not exactly, but in the right direction. How did you do it? It looks like now they are strings now and the numbers in front can be extracted by left(). I should have explained this in the question that those are values in scientific notation, and the "E4" are supposed to mean 10^4. Is there a way to get those values as string as well? row() might help?

Comment: I see, well in google sheets you are supposed to use `+10^` instead of `E` - sheet updated

Comment: Yes but the original data was manually typed into google sheet in this format....

Comment: so the question is how to correct all those errors in one go?

Comment: Yep, it looks like you have done it already. What did you use?

Comment: Thank you very much sir!